# jQuery wont open 2 consecutive modal dialogs correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to get a button inside a jQuery UI modal dialog to close itself and open another modal dialog.

The problem is that the second dialog when opened will always open without the screen overlay you expect from a modal dialog, as a result you can still click on the screen behind the modal.

The jQuery is as follows

```
$(function () {

    $("#DialogSelectEventType").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 400
    });

    $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog({
        model: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 450
    });

    $("#btnCreateToDo").click(function (e) {
        $("#DialogSelectEventType").dialog({ close: function (e, ui) {
            $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog("open");
        }}).dialog("close");
    });


});
```

I have also tried changing the handler to

```
$("#btnCreateToDo").click(function (e) {
    $("#DialogSelectEventType").dialog("close");
    $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog("open");
});
```

Which didn't help

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzKf7/)

Could someone please help me understand why this might be happening? Is this a bug or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, in the second dialog definition you have "**model : true**", when it is supposed to be "**modal : true**"

```
$(function () {

    $("#DialogSelectEventType").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 400
    });

    $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 450
    });

    $("#btnCreateToDo").click(function (e) {
        $("#DialogSelectEventType").dialog({ close: function (e, ui) {
            $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog("open");
        }}).dialog("close");
    });


});
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tzKf7/3/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Boy I feel like an idiot, thats what happens when you post code on stackoverflow at 5am. Thank you and sorry...

Comment: That has happened to all of us at one time or another... and if it hasn't... then you are not programming enough!

Answer (score 0):

Moving the .dialog definition into the click handler will do the trick.

```
$("#btnCreateToDo").click(function (e) { 
    $("#DialogCreateToDo").dialog({
        model: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 450
    });
});
```